# EnsureDispatch('Inventor.Application') doesn't catch existing running instance after frozen

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pywin32

does anybody have any guide why `from win32com.client.gencache import 
 EnsureDispatch; EnsureDispatch('Inventor.Application')` doesn't catch existing running instance after frozen by pyinstaller - it always start new instance in win 10, but works well (can catch existing application running process or create new one if not exist) when run from source(no pyinstaller frozen)? thanks!

edit: just find it works well in win 7 after frozen, so seems problem is pyinstaller in win 10? any guide? thanks!